# Organisation as a factor for safe behavior on the work-place

Tags: reference-request, io-psychology, human-factors

Many tools exists that allow the investigation of incidents and safe behavior on the workplace, such as the Human Factors Analysis and Classification System ([HFACS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Factors_Analysis_and_Classification_System)) or the System Hardware Environment Lifeware Lifeware ([SHELL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHELL_model)) model. Both describe the importance of the influence of the (culture within an) organisation on (un)safe behavior.

These tools are used to proof whether the organisation plays a role in an incident or, in general, in unsafe behavior. However, where did these models base the assumptions on that the organisation plays a role? **Was there scientific evidence that shows that the organisation can promote (un)safe behavior?**

Comment: This is quite interesting, however, I'm not sure to fully understand what you're after. Would this study http://doi.org/10.1016/j.aap.2009.08.008 fall under "scientific evidence … that the organization promotes (un)safe behavior"? Moreover, what do you mean with tools that are using their own tools as evidence for tools validity? Are you criticizing that they are self-refential in the sense of a recursive definition? I must admit that I don't know the tools you are referring to. I'm rather trying to understand the question on a general, methodological level.

Comment: @Will, That would indeed be an interesting paper for an answer. Questionnaires about people's attitude about safety would be nice thus, but also logical reasoning or accident investigations. What made people believe that the organization may play a part in human error.

Comment: Regardig the "using their own tools as evidence for... ". It was not necessarily criticism, but rather a remark stating the need (for me) to have evidence that is not provided by those tools themselves, because that would be too easy.

Comment: I'm reluctant to try an answer because there still some aspects of the question that I can't see through -- I'm sure it's me, not the question :-) .. would such a tool be more credible if it could prove to have sufficient convergent validity with another tool? That is, using multiple measures to asses the impact of organizational factors? Sorry, I'm doing my best and I do really like to question (even critically) the "stringency" (is this the term?) of methods.

Comment: As I have found out, the term theoretical "stringency" is used also in English: https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=%22theoretical+stringency%22&btnG=&hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5

Comment: @Will http://advancedd.wagpet.com.au/uploads/5/6/1/7/56178433/near_miss_article.pdf Did some further searching and this paper would be a nice start. It goes into the theoretical reason why and how an organization can influence (un)safe behavior and human error. I will try to formulate an answer myself, also, anytime soon.

Comment: May be of interest: Concept of "Common Source or Rater Bias" according to Podsakoff, P.M. et al. (2003). DOI: 10.1037/0021-9010.88.5.879. Says: "Some methods effects result from the fact that the respondent providing the measure of the predictor and criterion variable is the same person" (p. 881). -- I'm not in a hurry to answer this question, regards.

Comment: @RobinKramer Did you manage to formulate an answer to this?

Comment: @Chris no I haven't yet. Haven't had much time. I did think of studies by Reason on human error, and the Swiss cheese model, which could like be a basis for the answer